# Is it possible to combine a JavaScript app with Python in a shared hosting environment?

Tags: javascript, python

I am relatively new to most web development topics, however I have been coding with SAS (stats software) and SQL for a long time, so the coding itself is relatively easy to figure out however the where do I write the actual code pieces and have them communicate with each other is what trips me up completely.

I want to create a website using shared hosting and I want to write it with JavaScript and Python. I want to build an app with an image uploader written with JavaScript but then do some image analysis with Python and then have the data visualization with both JavaScript D3 and Python. I prefer SQL databases as I know SQL and that is usually included with most shared hosting plans anyway.

I am not expecting detailed answers but just pointers what I need to look into to make this possible and if I am even approaching the goal from the right perspective or if this is a much bigger undertaking for a newbie than I assume. The whole web server aspect of things is very confusing and I have written small projects with JavaScript and Node.js without ever realizing that Node.js is basically a webserver.

I am hoping I can just buy a host service, buy my domain and then just upload all the files (index, app.js and all that) into the cpanel?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is likely too broad and too opinion-based to be on-topic here. It sounds like you're looking for a tutorial and we don't provide those or find them for you. Here are some tips and questions that might help you proceed, or at least refine your question and try asking again: Why do you want to use JavaScript and Python? Are there specific libraries that you wish to use beyond D3? It's not clear why you want to use Python for data visualization, for example. Are you familiar with the client/server model, and specifically HTTP? How does your SQL database fit in?

Comment: I guess a simple no that is not possible or it is possible if you use <software> with other <software> would be enough to get me started. These are too many words for a search engine but if I can get hints at what I should possibly be looking at then I can narrow my research. Its more about can I combine these things rather than why I want it.

Comment: Except that's not quite right. I use Python with JavaScript all the time, e.g. via Django or Flask on the server and JS in the browser. You need to (a) wrap your head around the web's client / server model, (b) figure out why you want to use these languages and see if your needs align with Python on the back-end and JS on the front-end (JS can also run on the server but Python generally can't run in the browser, though there are some transpilers), (c) refine your question. Look up AJAX. Yes, it's possible to use JS and Python together. It might not be possible to use them the way you want to.

Comment: I really think it would help if you'd start by saying why you want to use Python. What led to that decision? Similarly for JS; is there anything other than D3 that makes it a good fit for you? There are so many ways to interpret your question that it's literally unanswerable. (Note that doing this won't magically make your question on-topic. But it will help you think about it and hopefully find some answers. You can read about what's on-topic here in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thank you, that helps. I am basically asking for cardinal directions rather than actually trying to get anywhere just yet. I will get better at asking the right questions and actual specific questions over time. For now, I am glad I know what planet I am on.